# Hybris How to distinguish if a voucher applies on order entry or on the order itself

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

How to show vouchers against products (order entry) in order details page.

In OrderData I see appliedVouchers but unable to distinguish voucher applied to which order entry.

```
final OrderData orderData = orderFacade.getOrderDetailsForCode(orderCode);
final List<VoucherData> voucherList = orderData.getAppliedVouchers();
```

Comment: Can you precise the version of hybris your using, since vouchers have been reworked in v6? Thanks.

Comment: Its 5.3. I found a way. I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flexible query to check which voucher is used in which order

```
select {vi.code}, {o.code} from 
{ VoucherInvalidation as vi
  join Order as o 
   on {o.pk} = {vi.order}
}
```

Basically voucher usage is stored in **VoucherInvalidation**